# backup of sharepoint server 2010 portal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, backup, restore

We use sharepoint server 2010 and windows server 2008 R2. 
Currently, I'm taking backup of sharepoint portal through sql server management studio by backing up the databases (listed for each web application in the central administration).

Will I be able to recover the sharepoint portal in case of crisis by restoring the databases? or m i missing something?

PS: When I initiate the backup using central administration (backup and restore link) the backup status shows as "in progress" but no backup file gets created ever.

Answer (score 0):

The backup process through Central Administration typically requires a significant amount of time, depending on your farm's size and the selections made for the backup.

Also, you can perform a backup using PowerShell as mentioned [**Backup and Restore Site Collection SharePoint**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/move-site-collection-to-another-web-application/).

**For Farm**

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} 
-Item <WebApplicationName> [-Verbose]
```

**For Site**

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity http://mcit-test -Path "C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"
```

**Regarding your current situation**, you should restore it by attaching it again to your destination farm or your current farm,

But this only backup contents and in this case, you will need to reconfigure application services again and all configuration settings.

> I recommend that you review the same scenario. [**Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2016/)

Comment: I'm trying to restore the .bak file created using Backup-SPSite command but it gives compatibility error. My source farm is on windows server 2008 R2 while the destination farm in a development farm is on windows 7 64 bit. I'm doing this operation only to check the integrity of backups and challenges expected while restoring them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the Backup of the Content Database of the web applications, by this you can restore the Content of your portal.

But if you have Custom solutions, Authentication and other custom changes to IIS or Web.config files...You have to Manually restore them.

In case of DR, You have to rebuild the farm, build the webapp, configure the Authentication, Deploy the solutions then restore the content db.

Comment: For now the only command I could get to work is Export-SPSite command which saves the exported site to .cmp file format. I'm not completely sure of the custom solutions and all. But I know the sites which are extremely important. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But this is not reliable in case of recovery

Comment: Yea I checked.  Some of the webparts didnt get restored. I have the content database backup for the web application.  Can i directly restore the database on my windows 7 machine and attach the restored database to the windows 7 web application? The window 7 machine and production server r on same network domain.  I dont want to break the production environment.

Comment: I would recoemend fix the issue and go for solid backup, So that on DR you can recover it.

Comment: Its the compatibility issue that doesnt let restore-spsite command to restore the .bak file on the windows 7 machine.  What is DR? :P

Comment: your both farm should be on same version level.what about the content Database backup and restore?

Comment: Thanks Waqas, I only have content database backup so I was scared to try the restore in case it too gives version mismatch error. So, I haven't tried restoring the content database to my windows 7 environment yet. Will try doing that soon n let you know.. :)